# Objective C- Whats the normal size of

Tags: uibutton, size, uilabel, default

I wanna make my ISomething app as native as possible and have no idea whats a good size for the Elements. Is there any normal/default/standard size for UIButtons or UILabels i can use? Are there any guidelines for something like that?

If not: What size would you (experienced developers) recommend? What size is normally used?

Answer (score 0):

There is a guideline made by Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

I suggest you to make a sketch before developing your app, this can help you to keep focus.